# ¿Por que no aparece información de mis registros de una tabla en PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Un saludo.

He creado un Query basico en el que quiero que me muestre los pedidos que me han echo en una fecha determinada.

En mi Query llamo a mis 3 tablas de la BD, pero cuando intento que mi consulta me muestre tambien la sucursal en la que se genero el folio del cliente, no aparece nada en la tabla.

```
select r.ID_CLIENTES,r.Num_Prestamo,c.NUM_FOLIO,r.SUCURSAL,r.status,b.Fecha_Recepcion,b.Fecha_Creacion
from CLIENTES c, BURO b, REPORTE_SOLICITUDES r
WHERE b.Fecha_Recepcion >= '9/05/2018'

and c.ID_CLIENTES = b.ID_CLIENTES
and c.ID_CLIENTES= r.ID_CLIENTES     
and b.ID_CLIENTES = r.ID_CLIENTES    


AND c.status IN ('18','21','19')
and c.CODIG_ESP ='0'

AND b.Fecha_Recepcion >= b.Fecha_Creacion
;
```

Cheque ya el nombre de la columna de la tabla y si aparece como tal el nombre de SUCURSAL en la tabla de REPORTE_SOLICITUDES.

Aqui la estructura de mis 3 tablas:

Estructura de REPORTE_SOLICITUDES:

```
COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE        NULLABLE   COLUMN_ID   
ID_CLIENTES      FLOAT  Yes                  1       
Num_Prestamo    NUMBER(12,0)        Yes      2  
SUCURSAL       VARCHAR2(60 BYTE)    Yes      3  
status       VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)     Yes      4
```

Estructura BURO:

```
    COLUMN_NAME       DATA_TYPE   NULLABLE  COLUMN_ID   
    ID_CLIENTES          FLOAT                1    
    Fecha_Creacion     DATE         Yes      2  
    Fecha_Creacion     DATE         Yes      3  
    NUM_FOLIO        NUMBER(12,0)   Yes      4  
    NUM_Prestamo    NUMBER(12,0)    Yes      5
```

Estructura CLIENTES:

```
COLUMN_NAME       DATA_TYPE       NULLABLE  COLUMN_ID   
ID_CLIENTES         FLOAT                      1
NUM_Prestamo     NUMBER(12,0)       Yes        2
status          VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)  Yes        3
NUM_FOLIO        NUMBER(12,0)       Yes        4
COFIG_ESP        NUMBER(12,0)       Yes        5
```

¿Es un error de logica en el programa?, ¿Falto que le pusiera mas condiciones?, ¿Algo mas?

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Hola @Sobyro, ¿podrías editar la pregunta y añadir las estructuras de tus tres tablas?

Comment: Seguro, dame un segundo por favor.

Comment: Ya hiciste un SELECT SUCURSAL FROM REPORTE_SOLICITUDES; para revisar que todos los renglones tengan un nombre de sucursal?

Comment: AlberTLopez deja lo checo.

Comment: AlbertLopez, Si ya lo puedo confirmar, todos los renglones de SUCURSAL de REPORTE_SOLICITUDES estan llenos, no hay ninguno nulo y aun asi, cunando los mando a llamar aparecen vacios.

Answer (score 1):

Y si el registro que estas buscando no esta en el rango que estas filtrando.. agregar también:

b.num_folio=c.num_folio

todos los campos pueden ser nulos? cual es el ID único?

Comment: Ha perdon error mio, se supone que ID_CLIENTES debe ser la primary Key, pero se me paso en la edicion colocarno como no nulo, gracias por el dato